# getUserInfo 401 - Internal Server error?

Tags: docusignapi

[getUserInfo within api Explorer dies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/esDZ7.png)

We were getting a 401 when attempting to use the REST getUserInfo endpoint.  So, we decided to test it using the Docusign provided API explorer.  Same error, but it also gives a response of "internal_server_error"

Does that endpoint just not work?

After further testing, we reauthenticated and used a brand new access token, instead of the one re-issued from the refresh token request, and it worked.  Not sure if that endpoint is not available after a refresh token has been re-issued?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the host for the method is different than for the other API methods, it's

- account-d.docusign.com for the developer sandbox
- account.docusign.com for the production platform.

It only works with a bearer token.

The refresh gives you a new bearer token, that should not be an issue.

Docs: https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/authentication/userinfo.html